# Definite article before scientific terms named after people

Tags: definite-articles, names, science

This is my first post here so I hope the format of my question is correct.

I am wondering whether it is necessary to use the definite article before physical quantities named after people, e.g.:

> *The* Heisenberg interaction comes from a complex interplay between *the* Pauli exclusion principle and *the* Coulomb interaction.

I think that it is incorrect to use the definite article if the name is in its possessive form:

> Can you explain Maxwell's equations to me?

but that we should put the article if the name is in its subjective form:

> Can you explain the Maxwell equations to me?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You could change your first sentence to:

> Heisenberg's interaction comes from a complex interplay between Pauli's exclusion principle and Coulomb's interaction.

And it would still make grammatical sense. However I would argue that although a principle or set of equations (or law) are quite explicit, an "interaction" isn't quite so well defined. Adding the definite article clears this up for non-experts. Although this is unlikely with the above sentence (at least for physicists), it may be possible for a reader to interpret that as a sentence about two people called Heisenberg and Coulomb having some sort of interaction!

On the other hand, I would never refer to "The Newton law of gravity". In that case, I would always use the possessive.

Comment: "Heisenberg's interaction" just doesn't sound right to me. "Heisenberg's Interaction Principle" perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

The presence of the definite article before a law or principle depends on the general usage of the term to date. This applies to laws in the legal sense as well.

For example, [the Mann Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann_Act) and [the Pauli Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) are always mentioned with the definite article. On the other hand, [Newton's Laws of Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) and [Hauser's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauser%27s_law) are not, and instead imply ownership of the eponymous law by the discoverer/proposer.